# How to force users to register after a number of requests

Tags: rest, tracking, authentication

Just was wondering how to go about requesting a user to sign up to continue to use some of my website functionality after lets say 5 requests.

How do I do this?  I basically have a rest api with a browser front end. The user may click on the link and perform lets say 5-10 free GET requests but I want to somehow keep track of the user and count the number of requests, and then ask the user to register to continue.

Would I need to store the User IP Address somewhere and keep track?  How would I do this?

Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IP address or cookies but both can be circumvented. If you really want to lock it down you may want to require an immediate registration or offer a reduced feature set until people register.

Comment: thanks @Carth. If using IP address or cookies I would be storing it at the db level and checking per request? Isnt that a bit heavy?

Comment: That's really up to your implementation but you could certainly check per session rather than per request.